# Safari rendering bug with CSS "clip"

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari, rendering

I have the following issue with Safari: http://cl.ly/ZlJ8

LiveDemo: http://drpdev.de/labs/example.html

full source code: http://jsfiddle.net/uqsghon7/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="rowcontainer">
    <div class="side">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
... (multiple times with different contents in .side)
```

and style:

```
.side {
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%; left: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 350px;
  ...
}
.row {
  ...
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rowcontainer {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.
Before I tried to achieve it only with position fixed inside the (relative positioned) div (without second container) and overflow hidden and it worked in all browser but not Firefox, so I had to do this workaround with css-clip... It actually works in Safari as well but it seems like Safari's render engine is not refreshing the view when scrolling...

Any ideas?

Comment: looks like some issue with css effects, can you paste the complete css?

Comment: We definitely need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sure, here is a full example http://jsfiddle.net/uqsghon7/ - which for some reason IS working in JSfiddle, but not when used outside (probably due to the iframe): http://drpdev.de/labs/example.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Very interesting.

I think I found the answer, but it involves a webkit-only hack. That bugs me a little but hopefully this still fits the bill.

Digging around for clipping/rendering issues, I stumbled across an SO question regarding [background-position and fixed-position elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571578/chrome-issue-with-background-attachment-fixed-and-position-fixed-elements)—the answer mentioned `-webkit-mask-image` as a webkit-only alternative to `clip: auto`.

It works for you, too—just adding the following CSS makes Safari happy:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
  .rowcontainer {
    clip: auto;
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 100%)
  }
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyesofjeremy/5a6btpz6/) and a [working model](http://jeremycarlson.com/example/fixed-hidden.htm).

I confess I don't really understand **why** it works. But it works in Chrome and Firefox, too.

IE9, however, is really not happy with this. IE11 shows the content of the divs but skips most of their background. Worth considering...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your demo works just fine, I'll check it out right now :)

Comment: It works well except in IE9 and 10, if you also know a workaround for these it would be perfect, otherwise I'll have to do some optional JS for these IE versions.

Comment: I did some investigations. First thought I had was adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` to the head, but that had no effect. I did see another SO answer with tantalizing clues @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/23859719/156645 - @lmeurs has a fiddle which seems to solve your problem, but only w/ relatively short `div` sizes. Once I made the containers taller, I ran into issues: http://jsfiddle.net/qbcaaddd/. I did notice that overflow:hidden is not actually needed.

Comment: Funnily enough trying to create the exact same interface. Unfortunately this fix causes issues for z-index, so the last slide is always on top: http://codepen.io/iamkeir/pen/qNGJRY I'm having a play to see if there is a workaround because it is *sooo* close!

Comment: My similar SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054433/backface-visibility-bug-in-firefox-ie-scroll-wipe-ui-like-life-socks/

Comment: I managed to fix it in Safari with `transform: perspective(0)` although still having issues in IE: http://codepen.io/iamkeir/pen/pbmxOP