# Backface visibility bug in Firefox/IE (scroll-wipe UI like Life Socks)

Tags: html, css

I was intrigued by the 'wiping scroll' functionality of http://lifesocks.me/ (which uses JS and Skrollr) and wanted to try and achieve it with CSS only, without hijacking native scrolling.

I managed to get pretty much 90% of the way there:
http://codepen.io/iamkeir/pen/yJKJNG

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
a { color: white; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }

.slide {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 10vw;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;    
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.slide__inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.slide--1 { background: red; }
.slide--2 { background: blue; }
.slide--3 { background: green; }
.slide--4 { background: grey; }
```

```html
<div class="slide slide--1">
  <div class="slide__inner"><a href="#test-1">Slide 1</a></div>
</div>

<div class="slide slide--2">
  <div class="slide__inner"><a href="#test-2">Slide 2</a></div>
</div>

<div class="slide slide--3">
  <div class="slide__inner"><a href="#test-3">Slide 3</a></div>
</div>

<div class="slide slide--4">
  <div class="slide__inner"><a href="#test-4">Slide 4</a></div>
</div>
```

Two issues remain:

1) The backface visibility trick does not seem to work in Firefox or IE11/Edge but I am not sure why.

2) Because of the z-index stack, you cannot interact with text/links on previous slides as the last slide is essentially 'on top'.

Regarding 2, I tried using JS to bring the 'current' slide to the top of the z-index stack but this is clunky - when is a slide 'current', when it is halfway up?

Would be great to get other's input on both the bug in 1 and any ideas for 2.

**EDIT**

Here is a Codepen of the JS 'focus' functionality - as I said, clunky!
http://codepen.io/iamkeir/pen/akxRwj

Comment: If they only wipe in one direction, it is considerably easier... but obviously not the intended functionality: http://codepen.io/iamkeir/pen/XKQxEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backface visibility "trick" sounds like a Chrome / Webkit bug to me. `overflow: hidden` is not supposed to apply to elements whose containing block is outside the `overflow: hidden` element.

The effect you're looking for can be achieved using the `clip` property. The `clip` property applies to all descendants, not just to containing block descendants. See [this BBC page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/resources/idt-248d9ac7-9784-4769-936a-8d3b435857a8) for an example.

Unfortunately, since the `clip` property only applies on `position: absolute` elements, you need three elements per slide. Here's how you do it:

```css
body { margin: 0; }
a { color: white; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }

.slide {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 10vw;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide__wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(auto auto auto auto);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.slide__inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.slide--1 { background: red; }
.slide--2 { background: blue; }
.slide--3 { background: green; }
.slide--4 { background: grey; }
```

```html
<div class="slide slide--1">
  <div class="slide__wrapper"><div class="slide__inner"><a href="#test-1">Slide 1</a></div></div>
</div>

<div class="slide slide--2">
  <div class="slide__wrapper"><div class="slide__inner"><a href="#test-2">Slide 2</a></div></div>
</div>

<div class="slide slide--3">
  <div class="slide__wrapper"><div class="slide__inner"><a href="#test-3">Slide 3</a></div></div>
</div>

<div class="slide slide--4">
  <div class="slide__wrapper"><div class="slide__inner"><a href="#test-4">Slide 4</a></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Markus, that's really useful. I was starting to wonder if it was actually Chrome/Safari that had the bug and that FF/IE were implementing things correctly. Great to see IE/Edge leading the pack as usual, though... grrr http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path I've accepted this answer though because it is technically correct :)

Comment: clip is different from clip-path. clip has very good support. It's being deprecated in favor of clip-path, but until clip-path has wide support (and actually clips fixed positioned elements, which it currently doesn't in at least Chrome), you can keep using clip.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately and frustratingly, now it is working in FF/IE but has this bug in Safari: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488059/safari-rendering-bug-with-css-clip ...currently playing around to see if I can fix it.

Comment: Ah ha, fixed in Safari with `transform: perspective(0)`, no idea why though: http://codepen.io/iamkeir/pen/pbmxOP - not working in IE11 however, seeing if there is a workaround.

Comment: Opted to revert to `position: absolute` in IE: http://codepen.io/iamkeir/pen/pbmxOP